# Decomposition and lossless joins

Tags: join, normalization

If someone walk me though the following questions I'd be very grateful.

> Consider a relation R(A, B, C, D, E) with the following functional dependencies:

```
A, B → C
D, E → C
B → D
```

> i) decompose R so that it is in 2nd normal form.
>
> Second part of the question: ii) suppose R is populated with the following data:

```
| A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | e1 |
| a2 | b1 | c2 | d1 | e2 |
| a2 | b2 | c1 | d3 | e2 |
```

> Show that your 2NF decomposition is lossless with respect to joins. To do this , produce a join expression amongst the decomposed tables, and show that its execution results in the original table above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and got it confirmed by the lecture, hopefully this will help someone else:

> i)
>
> The key is {A,B,E}.
>
> This means that FD1 and FD3 are both partial — but note that FD2 is
>   not, because {D,E} is not a partial key. The decomposition creates one
>   table for each of the FDs, and one for the PK FD:
>
> R1(A,B,E) R2(A,B,C) R3(B,D)

-

> ii) Using the above we can create the following tables:
>
> ```
>         `R1                R2              R3`
> | A  | B  | E  |   | A  | B  | C  |    | B  | D  |
> | a1 | b1 | e1 |   | a1 | b1 | c1 |    | b1 | d1 | 
> | a2 | b1 | e2 |   | a2 | b1 | c2 |    | b2 | d3 | 
> | a2 | b2 | e2 |   | a2 | b2 | c1 |
> ```
>
> Joining R1 and R2 gives:
>
> ```
>         R1R2                  R3
> | A  | B  | E  | C  |    | B  | D  | 
> | a1 | b1 | e1 | c1 |    | b1 | d1 | 
> | a2 | b1 | e2 | c2 |    | b2 | d3 | 
> | a2 | b2 | e2 | c1 |
> ```
>
> Joining R1R2 with R3:
>
> ```
> | A  | B  | E  | C  | D  | 
> | a1 | b1 | e1 | c1 | d1 | 
> | a2 | b1 | e2 | c2 | d1 | 
> | a2 | b2 | e2 | c1 | d3 |
> ```
>
> which is equal to:
>
> ```
> | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
> | a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | e1 |
> | a2 | b1 | c2 | d1 | e2 |
> | a2 | b2 | c1 | d3 | e2 |
> ```
>
> Hence decomposition is lossles with respect to joins.